# Can you reset a variable that stores the result of calling a function containing a closure?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to reset a variable that calls a function containing a closure? In the example below, this would be `counter`. (Be advised I'm new to closures so some of the comments might be wrong.)

```
function makeCounter() {
 let count = 0;
 return function() {
   ++count;
   return `count equals ${count}`; 
 };
};

// If you just call it two times without storing the result in a variable, count is reset to zero each time
console.log(makeCounter()()); // count equals 1
console.log(makeCounter()()); // count equals 1

// Since the counter variable holds a reference to the result of the outer function's call (which is the inner returned function, which "closes over" count), the JavaScript engine won't wipe it from memory.
let counter = makeCounter();

// As expected, calling counter again updates it (storing the updated count value)
console.log(counter()); // count equals 1
console.log(counter()); // count equals 2 <-- Can you reset count as stored in counter?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that code, it is not possible to reset `count` variable in any way, that's the power of closures.

What you can do is modify counter, and implement a method `reset`

```js
function makeCounter() {
 let count = 0;
 
 const counter = function() {
   ++count;
   return `count equals ${count}`; 
 }
 
 counter.reset = () => count = 0;
 
 return counter;
};

const counter = makeCounter();
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
counter.reset();
console.log(counter());
```

You can also add a reset argument to the function.

```
function makeCounter() {
    let count = 0;
    return function(reset) {
        if (reset)
            count = 0;
        ++count;
        return `count equals ${count}`;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At present, `counter` is only capable of accepting a single (unnamed) message, whose side effect is to increment the inner state `count`. In order to add a resetting functionality, you should augment `counter` so as to accept one more message.

In this respect, a possible approach is to introduce explicit message passing by way of string arguments (see also SICP, Exercise 3.11 in [Chapter 3](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/3_002e2.xhtml#g_t3_002e2_002e4)):

```js
 function makeCounter() {
     let count = 0;
     return function (msg) {
         switch (msg) {
             case 'increment': count++; return count;
             case 'reset': count = 0; break;
             default: throw new Error('unknown message');
         };
     };
 }

 let counter = makeCounter();
    
 console.log(counter('increment')); // output: 1
 console.log(counter('increment')); // output: 2
    
 counter('reset');
 console.log(counter('increment')); // output: 1
```

However, at this point we can mechanically replace the explicit dispatching on `msg` by taking advantage of JavaScript `object` type, as in:

```js
function makeCounter() {
    let count = 0;
    return {
        increment: function() { count++; return count; },
        reset: function() { count = 0; }
    };
}

let counter = makeCounter();

console.log(counter.increment());  // output: 1
console.log(counter.increment());  // output: 2
    
counter.reset();
console.log(counter.increment());  // output: 1
```

Therefore, a convenient solution might be achieved by having `makeCounter` return an `object` such that each message type is associated with the corresponding closure, as per the *[closures are a poor man's object](http://people.csail.mit.edu/gregs/ll1-discuss-archive-html/msg03277.html)* argument.

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing argument to counter function to reset it to 0:

```
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;
  return function(reset) {
    if (reset === true) {
      count = 0;
    }
    ++count;
    return `count equals ${count}`; 
  };
};

console.log(counter()); // count equals 1
console.log(counter()); // count equals 2
console.log(counter(true)); // count equals 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass reset count to function as shown below

```js
function makeCounter() {
 let count = 0;
 return function(startCount) {
   count = startCount ? startCount : ++count;
   return `count equals ${count}`; 
 };
};

let counter = makeCounter();

// As expected, calling counter again updates it (storing the updated count value)
console.log(counter()); // count equals 1
console.log(counter()); // count equals 2

// now counter will reset to value passed
console.log(counter(1));
```